# swap two keys using xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

My "return" key is broken. I followed the instructions here: http://www.ehow.com/how_2180748_command-linux-swap-keyboard-keys.html - hoping to reassign my | key as the new return key. My .xmodmaprc file reads as follows:

keycode 51 = 36

But the | key does *not* act as a return key. Nothing has changed. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thanks so much for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried logging in and out?

Comment: Thank you for replying - I ended up being able to make it work by using Autokey.

Answer (score 6):

Your xmodmap expression is wrong. It needs to be formatted like this:

```
keycode [keycode] = [keysym]
```

The *keysym* is the symbol name of the key you want the "|" key mapped to, which in your case is "Return". So your xmodmap expression needs to be:

```
keycode 51 = Return
```

Putting everything back together, the command you want to run is:

```
[~]$ xmodmap -e "keycode 51 = Return"
```

(Don't type the **[~]$** part, I'm just indicating that you need to run that from terminal).

If you want this to run each time you log in create a file called ~/.Xmodmap with the following contents:

```
keycode 51 = Return
```

I hope that works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the following in a terminal:

`xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc`