# Make a custom Compose Key for normal characters

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, keyboard

I've recently broken a key on my keyboard.  Unfortunately it was the vowel "o" (I'm using find and replace to fix this post).  So what I'd like to do is setup a compose key for hitting ComposeKey + "0" = "o", I've tried inputting this into the `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`

This is what I did:

```
<Multi_key> <0>                                 : "o"   U006F   # Simply, o
```

Although this doesn't work, even after restarting.  Am I missing something here?

If this is a silly method, is there some sort of alternative I can do?

Comment: Another solution would be to make use of the (possibly) unused Caps lock key. Switch the functionality of `o` with Caps Lock. This should help https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1104840

Comment: @JayAurabind I tried `setxkbmap -option caps:o`  I also tried doing the Unicode for "o", still did not work

Comment: You may use xmodmap http://askubuntu.com/questions/68819/swap-two-keys-using-xmodmap

Comment: @JayAurabind Thanks, if you put it into an answer I will accept it.  But I also have one more question.  Is there a list where I can get all the keycodes for the characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative method using `xmodmap`.

First, find out the keycode for the replacement key. Hit your required replacement key *after* executing the following command.

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
```

You will see keycode and its name echoed to screen. Close the other window which popped up with the command to exit `xev` command. Now just put the following lines in your `bash_profile` or somehow make these commands to run at startup:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 32 = Caps_Lock'
```

Comment: Although this is the best, simplest answer, it's worth noting that almost any time you want to have your keyboard do something special for you, it's worth taking a look at AutoKey. It's a a full keyboard macro processor that can do almost anything when you type a trigger phrase or press a hotkey.