# Left Ctrl Key doesn't work (but right one does)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My left ctrl key isn't working. The right ctrl key works fine. I'm not skilled at all with problem sovling in Linux. Could someone point me the right direction, please? From what I learn when I run xev is that the right key is correctly associated with Control_R, while the left key is not. How can I fix this? The same problem occurs under Ubuntu 18.04 and under Linux Mint (installed one after the other hoping the issue would resolve itself). Other keys seem to work fine so far.

Output of xev when I press the Ctrl keys:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 1330613, (-134,341), root:(727,796),
state 0x0, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 1330692, (-134,341), root:(727,796),
    state 0x4, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 1332145, (-134,341), root:(727,796),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 1332155, (-134,341), root:(727,796),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: keycode 151 should be your function key -- did you swap the Left Ctrl and Function key at some point?

Comment: no, it's a fresh installation. Hardly changed anything so far.

... but we're on something here! Fn and Ctrl are reversed... can I switch them so they match the sign printed on the keyboard?

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/68819/swap-two-keys-using-xmodmap (or search this site for "swap keys".

Comment: so ubfan1 was right: Switching of Fn and Ctrl had been enabled in the BIOS by a previous owner of the notebook. thanks for clarifying everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> should be available in BIOS. OEMs may have Windows apps to change it, but it's just another way of changing the same setting.

Comment: Jepp, Bios swapp it was. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @mathew7 Please elaborate on this. I have a Dell Inspiron and I see nothing on keyboards on its BIOS menu.

Comment: @Trunk My experience is with Lenvo, specifically Thinkpads. My 2013 x230 and 2018 x280 have the Fn key in the corner where 90% of keyboards have ctrl (fn,ctrl,win,alt,space order).
Searching for Dell Inspiron images, I see them having ctrl in corner. For such layouts, I don't think they would have the swap option.

Comment: @mathew7 Just found the answer. Open Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > CTRL Position  and then check the Bottom Left box. Ideally I'd like to move my Compose key across to the Right CTRL key but that's another puzzle . . .

Comment: Just commenting here to say that this worked on a Lenovo Legion laptop, where the "Fool proof Fn and Ctrl" option was on by default.